# VSIX Project Context Menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio 2017 extension, just for fun and to learn how VS extensibility works.

My extension must be usable from the Solution Explorer tab as a context menu button, but I would like to include it at a menu level that isn't root.

My goal is to put it in the "Add" sub-menu, but at the moment I'm only able to put it at root level (when you right-click the Project item, the menu entry is shown as the last of the context menu control).

How can I move it under the "Add" node?
Can it be done from the CommandPlacement tags I have configured in my .vsct file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use as parent of your command the IDG_VS_CTXT_PROJECT_ADD_ITEMS group id. If you are using CommandPlacement it would be:

```
  <CommandPlacement guid="..." id="..." priority="0x0001" >
     <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_CTXT_PROJECT_ADD_ITEMS"/>
  </CommandPlacement>
```

Remember:

- The parent of a group can be another group, a menu, a toolbar, a context menu, etc. either created by your extension or an existing one of VS, identified by prefix "IDM_". See [GUIDs and IDs of Visual Studio menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-menus?view=vs-2017) and [GUIDs and IDs of Visual Studio toolbars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-toolbars?view=vs-2017).
- The parent of a command is **always a group**, never a menu, context menu or toolbar. The group can be new (created by your extension) or an existing group of Visual Studio, identified by prefix "IDG_". You have some built-in Visual Studio groups in the links above, but for a more exhaustive list install the [ExtensionTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensibilityTools) extension (Mads Kristensen) that provides intellisense in the .vsct file or check the source code of its [VsctBuiltInCache.cs file](https://github.com/madskristensen/ExtensibilityTools/blob/master/src/VSCT/Completion/VsctBuiltInCache.cs).

Comment: Info you provided is very useful. How would you achieve this behaviour, but only on web projects nodes in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: It's a trial and error approach. Try the element containing "web" in the VsctBuiltInCache.cs that I linked

Comment: I'll try soon and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I think and hope this might help, though it is a general answer and not a specific one. Learn by example.

I also hope the WiX authors won't mind, but I believe the source for their **Visual Studio integration component** "**[WiX Votive](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/)**" is here: https://github.com/wixtoolset/VisualStudioExtension.

There is also this: https://github.com/wixtoolset/VisualStudio.wixext. I am not sure what this is to be honest. I should, but I don't. **Mr.Arnson - I summon theee** (WiX developer - The Matrix's got you).

---

[WiX Votive - VS Integration](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/) is part of the overall [WiX Toolset](http://www.wixtoolset.org) - which is a Windows Installer deployment solution capable of compiling MSI files from XML markup. MSI files are the binary deployment files used by [Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/windows-installer-portal) for deployment on Windows.

If of interest you **`1)`** [download and install WiX itself](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/) (currently 3.11.1), and **`2)`** download and install the correct Visual Studio integration (the marketplace links underneath the main download) making sure you get the correct version for your Visual Studio version - of course. Both downloads from the same link (or use the Visual Studio marketplace).

Here are some further details: [WiX quick-overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).

Comment: VisualStudioExtension is where Votive lives. VisualStudio.wixext is where WixToolset.VisualStudio.wixext.dll lives.